# setting a text input value via jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, text

I am trying to pass a textbox value from one section to another. I have :

```
<div data-role="page" id="landingPage">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    companyID<input type="text" name="companyID" id="companyID" value="" />
    <a href="#" id="goToPage2" data-transition="slide"><h1>Next</h1></a>
    <hr/>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
...
</div>
```

In my js:

```
$("#goToPage2").bind("click", function(event, ui) {
    var compID = $("#companyID");
    compID.val(999);
    compID.trigger('change');
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#page2", { reverse: false});
});
```

For some reason, I cannot populate the companyID field in page2. Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to data-ajax="false" or rel="external" fixed it.

```
<a href="#" id="goToPage2" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="false"><h1>Next</h1>
</a>
```